# Access Facebook without HTTPS

Tags: facebook, https

Is there a way to access Facebook without HTTPS? My proxy blocks HTTPS pages, so what can I do?

Comment: Is this really your proxy, or the proxy on a locked down network (work/school)?  If this on a network you don't control, you probably need to just give up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to turn off secure (https) browsing on Facebook:

- Go to [Account Security Settings Tab](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security)
- The first choice is `Secure Browsing` click `Edit` on the right side of that line
- Uncheck the box
- Click `Save Changes`

Answer (score 1):

I would change proxy.

I can't think of a logical or reasonable reason to block HTTPS as so many websites use it.

Is it possible to use a proxy client on your PC which hides your IP address from your proxy which blocks HTTPS?

See this search:
http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?tag=mncol%3Bsort%3Bp&query=anonymous+ip+address+free&searchtype=downloads&filter=platform%3DWindows&filterName=platform%3DWindows&sort=popularity+asc&rpp=10

Comment: Additionally, I can't think of a logical or reasonable reason to access Facebook *without* HTTPS - even if it's your only option.

Comment: @Steve, it is someone common to see this blocked on some networks to force everything to through a proxy for filtering/monitoring.  Depending on they network they may permit some HTTPS traffic.

Comment: @Iszi I would have agreed you with you 100% (that there is no reasonable reason to access Facebook without HTTPS), until seeing this http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26391/why-does-facebook-apps-require-disabling-https a few days ago. It is disquieting that this is the case re security POV. I know, I know, https is not the be all and end all of security, but it is a minimal something. But it also gets in the way sometimes... Same is true in certain contexts for MSN and Google.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is also useful. I live in China and I have a transparent proxy on my network which routes traffic for well-known blocked sites in China to a reverse proxy in Eurpe. Since transparent proxies can't handle https, hence the need for a ssl-less access.

For becko, you can still use m.facebook.com with the so called "alternative login method", which is no other than the so desired ssl-less. Once authenticated you can return to www.facebook.com normally.

If you are in China as I do you might need to add a /etc/hosts line (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) to define the correct dns for m.facebook.com to:

66.220.158.19   m.facebook.com

Good luck!

Comment: Same problem here in Tajikistan, but the m.fb.com version works no longer!